# mysql catorgorize and when and else

Tags: mysql

my table WebLog has retcode,ipno,orgdate and zone.

I am trying to make a query using when and else statements to categorize the retcodes for each of the numeric values in the retcode fields and lump all of the NULLs into the ELSE category.

Then for each of these categories count the number of records in each group and average the number of bytes.

so far i have come up with this but all i get is the NULLs grouped in a retcode column.

can someone point me in the right direction.

```
SELECT CASE retcode
WHEN retcode = ipno THEN "ret"
ELSE NULL END AS retcode
FROM WebLog
GROUP BY ipno LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Comparing non-aggregated columns (`retcode`) to aggregated columns (`ipno`) makes no sense, because since many values share one ipno, how is MySQL going to know which `retcode` to pick? (Answer - it picks randomly)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN retcode = ipno THEN "ret"
ELSE NULL END AS retcode
FROM WebLog
GROUP BY ipno LIMIT 10;
```

or

```
SELECT CASE retcode
WHEN ipno THEN "ret"
ELSE NULL END AS retcode
FROM WebLog
GROUP BY ipno LIMIT 10;
```

[12.4. Control Flow Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case)

```
CASE value 
    WHEN [compare_value] 
    THEN result 
    [WHEN [compare_value] THEN result ...] 
    [ELSE result] 
END

CASE 
    WHEN [condition] 
    THEN result 
    [WHEN [condition] THEN result ...] 
    [ELSE result] 
END
```

Comment: i get the same result but ill continue this in the morning when i get to work thanks for your help its really appriciated

Comment: here is what i got but im told i need IF statements for my retcode column but i keep getting errors when i try that. here is what i have now                                                                                                                                        SELECT retcode, ipno, COUNT(*) AS Num_Of_Ip,   
   SUM(IF(retcode=404,1,0)) AS 'IP_ADDY'
   FROM WebLog
   GROUP BY ipno
   ORDER BY retcode DESC LIMIT 10;
END